# Sqlite Datetime Type Issue

Tags: java, sqlite

I try to insert a datetime into a sqlite DB from Java, but things are weird.

When I use the code `Calendar.getInstance().getTime()` to insert, the value in table is (for example) 1359960520718.
When I use the the string `2010-01-01` to insert into the table, the value is normal: 2010-01-01.

But when I use the string `2010-21-51` to insert into the table, the value in the table is 2010-21-51. That's an invalid date.
What's wrong with it?

Comment: What makes you think that `2010-21-51` is not invalid date?

Comment: If the data type of the column is String, it will accept any valid string. And 2010-21-51 is a valid string.

Comment: I make a slip in writing.I have edited it again.2010-21-51 is an invalid date.

Comment: But I set the column's data type as DATETIME.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because SQLite is dynamically typed. You can write value of any type into any column, and it won't complain - it may silently store it in different type.

According to [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), datetime can be stored as

- TEXT as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS").
- REAL as Julian day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic Gregorian calendar.
- INTEGER as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.

In your case, SQLite was unable to convert invalid date into INTEGER format, and was forced to store it as standard string instead. This date is invalid, but SQLite does not care.

Comment: Actually, there are cases where storing formally-invalid data is actually more useful than datatype enforcement; it's only when you're wanting to query against the value that it matters (from a DB perspective; apps using the DB might care a lot more!)

Answer (score 1):

you can new a date of Date type with the param from Calendar.getInstance().getTime(),like:

```
Date date = new Date(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

and then,maybe you shold use SimpleDateFormate to formate the date as a String you need,like:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String timeStr = df.format(date);
```

and then,you an insert the timeStr into your table...  you also have other methods if you do something in your insert statement of your database

Comment: If you're getting into parsing and formatting dates in Java, do consider using the Joda-time library. Really.